# How merge two arrays conditional on inner keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, key, push

I have two arrays which look like below:

```
  array1 = [
  {
    id: 'A',
    values: [
      { date: '1/1/2022', measure: 231 },
      { date: '1/2/2022', measure: 31 },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'B',
    values: [
      { date: '1/1/2020', measure: 51 },
      { date: '1/2/2020', measure: 66 },
    ],
  },
];
const array2 = [
  {
    id: 'AA',
    values: [
      { date: '1/1/2022', measure: 23 },
      { date: '1/2/2022', measure: 67 },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'BB',
    values: [
      { date: '1/1/2020', measure: 90 },
      { date: '1/2/2020', measure: 100 },
    ],
  },
];
```

The arrays have unequal ids but it is known key A should be merged with AA, B should be merged with BB and so on. Dates are equal in case of A and AA, B and BB, etc.

I want to merge A and AA (and rest) as below:

```
arrayFinall = [
 { 
   id: 'A-AA',
   values: [
     {date:"1/1/2022", measure1: 231, measure2: 23 },
     {date: "1/2/2022", measure1: 31, measure2: 67}},
   ],

{
   id: 'B-BB',
   values: [
     {date:"1/1/2020", measure1: 51, measure1: 90}, 
     {date:"1/2/2020", measure1: 66, measure1: 100},
}
```

]

Either creating a new array that has both measures and the date for a new key A-AA
or
push measure from array2 into appropriate position in array 1 work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array1 = [
  {
    id: 'A',
    values: [
      { date: '1/1/2022', measure: 231 },
      { date: '1/2/2022', measure: 31 },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'B',
    values: [
      { date: '1/1/2020', measure: 51 },
      { date: '1/2/2020', measure: 66 },
    ],
  },
];
const array2 = [
  {
    id: 'AA',
    values: [
      { date: '1/1/2022', measure: 23 },
      { date: '1/2/2022', measure: 67 },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'BB',
    values: [
      { date: '1/1/2020', measure: 90 },
      { date: '1/2/2020', measure: 100 },
    ],
  },
];
function mergeArrays(array1, array2) {
  const result = [];
  const keys = Object.keys(array1);
  keys.forEach((key) => {
    const array1Values = array1[key].values;
    const array2Values = array2[key].values;
    const values = [];
    array1Values.forEach((value) => {
      const date = value.date;
      const measure1 = value.measure;
      const measure2 = array2Values.find((value2) => value2.date === date).measure;
      values.push({ date, measure1, measure2 });
    });
    result.push({ id: `${array1[key].id}-${array2[key].id}`, values });
  });
  return result;
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(mergeArrays(array1, array2), null, 2));
```